# What is the difference between Priority and Depends on Method in TestNG?

Tags: testng

I am lagging behind to understand the concept of `dependsOnMethods` and `priority`. I googled but I didn't get enough info about this. A one line answer will be greatly appreciated. 
Can we write multiple methods with the same priority?

Comment: When we use Depends On the subsequent methods will be skipped when your methods fail. In case of priority all the test cases will run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, definitely we can write multiple methods with same priority but disadvantage of using this-There is no guarantee which method will run first,
So-
Instead of this,you can use **'dependsOnGroups'** annotation from TestNG which you can easily perform stepwise operations.

```
@Test(priority=1)
 public void Login() 
{ 
  System.out.println("LogIn Test code.");
  Assert.assertTrue(5>6, "Condition Is False.");
}

@Test(priority=1, dependsOnMethods={"Login"}) 
public void checkMail() 
{ 
  System.out.println("checkMail Test code.");
}

@Test(priority=1,dependsOnMethods={"Login","checkMail"}) 
public void LogOut() 
{ 
  System.out.println("LogOut Test code.");
}

----------------------
Instead of this you can use -'dependsOnGroups' annotation.

@Test(groups = { "A" })
   public void login() 
  {
      System.out.println("PrintMessage()");
  }
.
.
.
.

@Test(dependsOnGroups = { "A" }) 
public void LogOut() 
{ 
  System.out.println("LogOut Test code.");
}
```

Comment: Test(priority=1,dependsOnMethods={"Login","checkMail"}) how this will work ? is it execute login method then checkmail?

Comment: This test will run unless & until- "Login","checkMail"
these two methods successfully run & pass. If one method gets failed last method i.e-logout test will not run.
It means logout test is depends on both tests.

Comment: @sameer.....got it ? let me know if you have any doubts

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can write multiple methods with the same priority (quite similar to not use any priority - all methods has the same default priority).
About dependsOn annotation in a few words:

**dependsOnMethods**

> There is no guarantee on the order on which the methods depended upon
>   will be run, but you are guaranteed that all these methods will be run
>   before the test method that contains this annotation is run.

More complex answer you can find here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36713748/4855333